# How can I make an object disappear on the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So basically I just want to have the user click on an NSButton, and have it disappear once it is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: I *almost* posted an answer involving Houdini, several rabbits, a car battery, and a few pounds of TNT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NSButton* is a sublcass of [*NSView*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay), which has these two handy methods:

- [`- (void) removeFromSuperview`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/removeFromSuperview)
- [`- (void) setHidden:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setHidden%3a)

Whichever you need depends on what exactly your application should do.

Answer (score 2):

Your button's action method might look like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [[self button] setHidden:YES];
}
```

It might be a better idea to disable it instead:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [[self button] setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Not a judgement call, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

`-removeFromSuperview` should do what you want:

```
NSbutton *myButton = button;

[myButton removeFrowSuperview];
```